# In what language did the /**/ comment style originate?

Tags: javascript, css, comments

I remember reading it once, but can't find it anymore. I think the text mentioned that the `/**/` style of commenting, that can be found in css and js, originated from one common ancestor.

Does anyone know what that common ancestor is?

Comment: I'd imagine that this is from C originally.

Comment: The `/* */` comments pre-date C and Unix.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about history of a notation, not a practical programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PL/I programming language, specified by IBM in the early '60s and first implemented around 1964, had `/* */` comment blocks.

The PL/I language was (sort-of) subsetted to create the EPL language for the Multics operating system a couple years after that (around 1966). EPL also had `/* */` comments, and was (significantly) an inspiration for the subsequent Bell Labs work on Unix. (The name "Unix" is clearly a derivation.) Ken Thompson worked as a researcher using Multics in those years before he left that work and started in on Unix in 1969.

Answer (score 2):

I followed http://rigaux.org/language-study/diagram.png back from C. The languages B & PL/I (precursors to C) have `/* */` style comments (http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/kbman.html), but it looks like their ancestor ALGOL only uses single-line comments, where the line starts with the word `comment`.

So it looks like B or PL/I might have introduced the `/* */` style comment.   It appears that Dennie Van Tassel - who has an entire webpage devoted to commenting in programming languages - came to the same conclusion back in 2004, "It is obvious that the C style comments have won, but they came from B (ALGOL?? which one or did I make this up)." - http://www.gavilan.edu/csis/languages/comments.html

Comment: Not Algol (at least, not Algol 60) - block comments in Algol 60 opened with `!+` and closed with `!-`, and I *think* those had to be at the beginning of the line but I'm not sure.

Comment: No wait; that's not Algol. I don't remember what it was that had the `!+ !-` convention. Funny thing is that I just saw it recently while reading some paper.

Comment: @Pointy - According to the great and mighty Wikipedia (i.e. buyer beware), ALGOL 60 comments were single-lined and always started with the keyword `comment`. ALGOL 68 introduced a few new keywords (`comment`, `co`, `#`, & `£`), but comments were still single-lined.  And just to be clear, the quote in my answer is from Dennie Van Tassel. I referenced his quote, because he too was leaning toward B as the originating language for the `/* */` style quote.

Comment: Right. I wish I could remember what language did the `!+` thing. Anyway, PL/I and EPL definitely did `/* */` and they predated B and C by half a decade; Ken Thompson is obviously the most likely person to have picked up a liking for the convention during his time working with Multics.

Comment: @Pointy - I'd add this comment to your answer (I'm thinking your answer is the actual correct answer and am disappointed that it is currently last on the page), but I don't have the necessary reputation.    
  
PL/I definitely has `/* */` style comments and definitely predates B.  Were `/* */` comments in PL/I from the beginning or were they added in at a later date?

Comment: @Pointy - I have gained some metaBLISS from learning the answer to your !+ quest!

Comment: Not super-sure about PL/I in its original incarnation, but I'm pretty sure that EPL (Multics) used `/* */` by 1966 or so.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_%28computer_programming%29#Styles it was branded by Holub for C and C++. Depending on your level of detail, the original "idea" of this commenting style can be awarded to either him, Bell Labs (Creators of C), or Dennis Ritchie (specific author of C)

Further reading on Dennis Ritchie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie

Further reading on Allen Holub: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allen_Holub

Comment: You're most welcome. Also welcome to StackOverflow! If someone answered your question well it'd be nice of you to mark it as correct by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: The `/* */` comment syntax was also available in the language `B`, also devised by Thompson around 1969. He was at that time at least clearly a man opposed to typing.

Comment: And BCPL, from about 1966, had `//` comments.

Comment: From what I've been looking at, the C language was definitely not the first time `/* */` were seen.